# display: flex; vs calc(); performance

Tags: html, css, performance, flexbox, calc

I came up today in a discussion where I'm wondering what is the most performant way of having two div's beside each other.

On one side, i love using `display:flex;`, on the other side there is the option to use `calc()`, the reason is our div has padding and we need to reduce the width by the padding. Case:

```
<div class='container'>
 <div class='inner'></div>
 <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

Both should be on 50% width. The default css is:

```
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
 box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.inner {
 width: 50%;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

The `display:flex;` way would be additional:

```
.container {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 align-items: stretch;
 align-content: stretch;
}
```

The `calc()` way would be:

```
.inner {
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 display: inline-block;
}
```

or:

```
.inner {
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 float: left;
}
```

I do not want any table layout in my css.
Additionally, we do not need to take care of the browser versions, this should be only functional in the latest versions, always.

What would be recommended to use? What has more performance?

I already found an article that the performance has been increased already a lot. [Link](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/10/Flexbox-layout-isn-t-slow)

Comment: This is also my usecase, a colleague doesnt liked this display type, so we discussed.
Also I have never noticed any performance issue, this is why im wondering what is generally faster now.

Comment: I don't know of any direct test results, but `display: flex` performs better in my experience

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran a simple test out of curiosity and there don't seem to be any differences in performance between [float+calc](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNGawN) vs [flex](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPyZpW), other than IE rendering both much slower than FF and Chrome.

From a [related article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/10/Flexbox-layout-isn-t-slow):

> The new flexbox code has a lot fewer multi-pass layout codepaths. You
>   can still hit multi-pass codepaths pretty easily though (e.g.
>   flex-align: stretch is often 2-pass). In general, it should be much
>   faster in the common case, but you can construct a case where it’s
>   equally as slow.
>
> That said, if you can get away with it, regular block layout
>   (non-float), will usually be as fast or faster than new flexbox since
>   it’s always single-pass. But new flexbox should be faster than using
>   tables or writing custom JS-base layout code.

I'm pretty sure that `calc()` makes a block layout require multiple passes too :)

---

LE: There was [a bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=946167) that made reflows very slow when you had 4-5 nested flexboxes, but it was fixed in the latest versions (37+).

Comment: Is performance really an issue?
Even if it is slower, who (except developers), really plays with their window size?

Comment: @twicejr - performance is critical in an example whereby you are creating split screens with the ability to slide the gutter side to side and might want to use calc/flex to adjust the panels on each side.

Comment: Let it be. Let people move over from IE ;)
I doubt it would really be noticable.